# VCR recording an external API protected by a temporary access token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, vcr

I would like to test several end points of an external API that require an access token in order to use them. The problem is that the access token expires after 60 minutes.

The only options I can think of are:

1. To hard code the access token for a one time recording.
2. Write a capybara before block that follows the oauth flow and gets a new access token. Side note: Can anyone provide an example like this with oauth?
3. Just stub the hole thing with something like webmock.

I'd prefer option two due to the ability to re-record.

Answer (score -4):

just simply extend token expires time to 1d, { expiresIn: '1d' }